# Using eval securely to execute functions

Tags: python, eval

```
def myFunc(arg1, arg2):
    print "This is a test with " + arg1 + " and " + arg2

while (input != "quit"):
    input = raw_input("> ")

    if input != "quit":
        eval(input)
```

This code gives me a prompt, allowing me to invoke `myFunc` with parameters I want. I know that `eval` can be dangerous if a dictionary is not supplied, so I added this:

```
eval(input, {"__builtins__": {} }
```

Now I can no longer invoke `myFunc`. How do I fix this without leaving `eval` open to exploits?

Comment: @S.Lott, `eval` does always introduce a security hole, but not that particular one; statements (including `import`) cannot be executed in an `eval`, which only evaluates expressions.

Comment: @Mike: Be aware of the `__import__` function: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__

Comment: **There is no way to make `eval` safe.** Just hiding the builtins doesn't even begin to address the problem. For example, evaled code can easily get them back from `myFunc.func_globals['__builtins__']`.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, I am aware of the `__import__` function, but that wasn't pertinent to S.Lott's now-deleted post. In any event, I'm sorry to post something like I did, since by debunking one thing that isn't possible it might sound like I'm encouraging use of `eval`. **`eval` always introduces a security hole**, and is not how you interpret user code.

Comment: `eval("' '*1000000000*1000000000", {"__builtins__": {}, "myFunc": myFunc})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to use `myFunc`:

```
eval(input, {"__builtins__": {}, "myFunc": myFunc})
```

However, as others have pointed out, using `eval` is inherently insecure, and still vulnerabe to exploits.

Comment: This does give access to `myFunc` but doesn't accomplish the overall goal of executing the function securely. `eval` cannot be used for that, especially not this easily.

Answer (score 1):

Your question, "How do I fix this without leaving `eval` open to exploits?", isn't the right one—`eval` is vulnerable to exploits, period. Not introducing `__builtins__` into the global namespace of the evaluated code does not make the `__builtin__` module impossible to access, and it doesn't close off other points of entry.

If you explained more about the problem you are trying to solve, someone may be able to suggest a secure option to accomplish your goals.

Comment: I know there are more secure options, but I have a school assignment that says I have to use `eval` in this particular script (even though I can still have it process `'*' * 10000000` so that Python goes nuts).

Comment: Okay, just keep in mind that since you are stuck using `eval`, your script is going to be vulnerable to exploits including impossibly-long calculations as well as access to `__builtins__` against your wishes, even with the code above. If one wishes to execute arbitrary Python code securely, you would sandbox the interpreter at an OS level and run it under a supervisor, like they do at http://codepad.org/, but I doubt you really care to go through that trouble for your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a demonstration of how eval is still dangerous even with the builtins removed, see this:  [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).  There are examples there of segfaulting the CPython interpreter, or of exiting it directly.